# How do I implement a typescript service worker with vite-plugin-pwa in Vue 3

Tags: typescript, progressive-web-apps, vuejs3, workbox, vite

I want to make a single-page application available for offline. So I want to use a PWA Service Worker in my Vue webapp and use typescript and workbox for it. I followed the examples from https://vite-plugin-pwa.netlify.app/guide/inject-manifest.html#typescript-support.

When building the typescript I get many `TS2403` errors like:

```
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:5720:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'onoffline' must be of type '((this: Window, ev: Event) => any) | null', but here has type '((this: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope, ev: Event) => any) | null'.
// ...
Found 21 errors in 2 files.

Errors  Files
     3  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:25
    18  node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:25
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! vite-project@0.0.0 build: `vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
```

Here are the steps I did.

The first thing I did was to install the Vite plugin:

```
npm i vite-plugin-pwa -D
```

then to the `vite.config.ts` I added the

```js
import { VitePWA } from "vite-plugin-pwa";
//...
VitePWA({
    strategies: 'generateSW', // default
    includeAssets: [ "favicon.svg", /* ... */ ],
    manifest: {
      name: "Name of your app", 
      // ...
    },
}),
// ...
```

First build here was working fine, but with the next steps I get the error.

Now in the `vite.config.ts` I added the config for using a typescript

```js
VitePWA({
    srcDir: 'src',
    filename: 'sw.ts',
    workbox: { 
        swDest: "sw.js"
    },
    strategies: 'injectManifest', // changed
    // ...
```

then changed the `tsconfig.json` (added WebWorker to lib and  added types):

```json
//"lib": ["esnext", "dom" ], // before
"lib": ["esnext", "dom", "WebWorker"],
"types": ["vite-plugin-pwa/client"]
```

and finally added the `sw.ts` in the src folder:

```js
/// <reference lib="WebWorker" />
import { skipWaiting, clientsClaim } from "workbox-core"
import { precacheAndRoute } from "workbox-precaching";

declare const self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope

precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
skipWaiting();
clientsClaim();
```

Comment: see also [msw in browser doesn't work with Vite](https://github.com/mswjs/msw/issues/695) and [msw-ts-vitejs](https://github.com/msutkowski/msw-ts-vitejs)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend removing `"WebWorker"` from your `tsconfig.json`'s `lib` property, and just use the `/// <reference lib="webworker" />` triple-slash directive to add the `lib` reference at the top of your `sw.ts` file.

You can see an [example project with this setup](https://github.com/jeffposnick/yt-playlist-notifier/tree/d038e795d2e876b178884212cabd5430971e28bb) if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the example project. Removing the `"WebWorker"` from the lib was half the way.

To resolve the problem I had to add `"exclude": ["src/sw.ts"],` in `tsconfig.json`.
Isn't this bad practice to exclude the file? Then I'm able to write code that is not type safe.

Comment: You can isolate the ServiceWorker code which shouldn't have any connection to your main site code beyond importing shared/common libraries. This can be done with a `tsconfig.sw.json` that's only for the Service Worker logic.